# Can't import/reference third party library in Angular2

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, webpack, asp.net-core

sorry this question has been asked so many times. I've tried so much to try and get this working for the last few days and I feel like I've missed something trivial which is making this impossible.

Background: 
Using .NET Core as the back end to an Angular2 front end and webpack 2.2.1 to deploy the js/css. (I'm using the following template btw, http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/)

I'm trying to reference alertifyjs into a typescript service (notifications.service.ts) with the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import * as alertify from 'alertifyjs';

declare var alertify: any;
//var alertify = require('alertify.js');

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
    private _notifier: any = alertify;
    constructor() {
    }
```

So my current issue is how do I:

1. Check if alertifyjs is actually being rendered properly through webpack (I tried calling alertify through the console of the developer tools and it didn't work) -This isn't essential but its good learning
2. Get alertify to work correctly through webpack
3. Reference and use alertify in Angular2

Thanks for any help in advance and I'm super super sorry if this has been answered somewhere on StackOverflow and I missed it!

Also, my webpack config is as follows:

```
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '', '.js' ]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        debug: true,
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css']) }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router',
            '@angular/platform-server',
            'angular2-universal',
            'angular2-universal-polyfills',
            'bootstrap',
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'es6-shim',
            'es6-promise',
            'jquery',
            'zone.js',
            'alertifyjs',
            //'systemjs',
            'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]_[hash]',
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', alertify: 'alertifyjs' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [ ] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false } })
    ])
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commented `import`/`require`s are out of sync with your Webpack config for one thing. This may or may not be the issue but it will cause trouble.

Lets take a look

```
// fine if 'alertifyjs' is the name of the package
import * as alertify from 'alertifyjs';
```

Then we see this

```
declare var alertify: any;
```

That suggests you want to the global, a very different thing and, since you are relying on Webpack to provide it, this won't work unless *alertifyjs* always creates a global, which would be terrible!
Fortunately, we see that it does not create a global unless there is no loader available for it https://github.com/MohammadYounes/AlertifyJS/blob/master/build/alertify.js#L3571

Then we see this.

```
var alertify = require('alertify.js');
```

This is weird. First of all this is inconsistent with the module specifier used in the `import` statement above which was `"alertifyjs"`. And lastly, when importing a CommonJS dependency in TypeScript using CommonJS style, do not use `var` or `let` or even `const`, use `import`. That said this style should be avoided.

Now moving to our Webpack configuration

We see under `entry`

```
vendor: [
    .....
    'alertifyjs',
    .....
]
```

Again the question is what is the name of the package? `'alertify.js'` or `'alterfyjs'` or

But from here on we get into even deeper trouble
Continuing with the Webpack configuration we see

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', alertify: 'alertifyjs' }),
// Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package
// (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
```

So what do we call it and is it a module or global?

We must decide.

Lets remove all of the Webpack config related to alertify:
Remove it from

```
entry.vendor
```

remove it from

```
webpack.ProvidePlugin({ ... })
```

Now lets clean up the TypeScript

**Remove**

```
declare var alertify: any;
```

*Add*

```
import * as AlertifyJS from 'alertifyjs';
```

Why? Because it will be installed in the node modules folder under that package name and because it is good practice to name the import after the library which is called *AlertifyJS* not *alertify*

And finally, we will fix this

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
    private _notifier: any = alertify;
    .....
}
```

because it is bad code and replace it with this

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
    // :any in an assignment context is perhaps the worst TypeScript code we could write.
    notifier = AlertifyJS;
    .....
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the comprehensive answer, I'll give this a shot now

Comment: Damn you are a god send. So much effort to get that working and you hit it right on the head perfectly.

Comment: glad to be of assistance :)